# Is there a way to skip an orchestration step based on a query parameter?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a default user journey for signing up a user and I am trying to make an RP policy that will skip the first orchestration step so the user can go directly to signing up instead of logging in.

I am running into trouble with accomplishing this. From my research, I understand that we cannot pass a query parameter in and use it for a non-REST technical profile.

I have tried the following:

  Adding input claim and settings the default value of the RP

  Having the RP policy "IncludeClaimsFromTechnicalProfile" which sets the default value

  Attempted to overwrite the OrchestrationStep and replace the step type to "noop" which causes it to error out

What I am trying to do is to avoid having to write a new user journey because if the default journey changes, then it will duplicate work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you can resolve the query param in the first step but at that point you’re too late if step 1 is the sign in page. So you can either call a rest api in step 1 to echo this param or just copy the UserJourney into a new one without step 1 present. Then call the new journey id in your app instead of passing a query param.

Comment: Hi jas. I have tried to resolve the query parameter in step 1 with the ouauth key value pair Claim resolves and was unable to retrieve the value.

Comment: What is the protocol provider in the first step?

Comment: It is claimsproviderselection but I also tried claimsexchange.

Comment: If your trying to skip the first step, you cant be resolving the claim in the first step if its a selfAsserted type - since the page is displayed and the claim is resolved togethor. You got to resolve the claim in the first step in a protocol provider that supports claims resolving and does not display a page. Then use it to skip subsequent steps. My answer still applies. Either call a rest api in step 1 to echo this param or just copy the UserJourney into a new one without step 1 present.